# Regex: Comma delimited string(suburb,state,postcode)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that's made up of a suburb, state and postcode(all for Australia) that need to validate before submitting to a form.

Suburb - should be A-Z
State - A-Z and 2-3 in length
Postcode - Numbers only and 3-4 digits only

For example

```
RAPID CREEK, NT, 810
```

I came up with this:

```
^([A-Za-z])+(,)([A-Za-z]{2,3})+(,)([0-9]{3,4})
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You missed the dollar. `^([A-Za-z]+)(,)([A-Za-z]{2,3})(,)([0-9]{3,4})$`

Comment: `should be A-Z`, you mean both upper and lower case letters?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have tried your suggestion: RAPID CREEK, NT, 810 - no match, RAPID CREEK,NT,810 - no match while RAPID,NT,810 - match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `+` after `([A-Za-z]{2,3})` and add `$` at the last.

```
^([A-Z]+(?:\s[A-Z]+)*),\s*([A-Z]{2,3}),\s*([0-9]{3,4})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qJ7eI8/3)